# How can I quickly re-image a Windows machine?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows machine that I’m using for software testing. I have a fresh and up-to-date installation of Windows on it right now; I’d like to be able to quickly restore it to this state again later. In other words, I want to be able to push a button and completely replace the content of the hard drive with the current content of the hard drive, discarding any files I might have created or applications and drivers I might have installed. What is the quickest and least painful way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are dozens of applications that will create a sector-by-sector image of the hdd.  How quickly this takes depends on the size of the hdd.  Its by far the most effective way to create an image of a hdd.

Comment: A VM should be the way to go. But you'll need to set it up - say, VirtualBox. You can then take a snapshot of an installation and "revert" it as and when your development needs resetting. If you don't want a VM then I would suggest taking a WIM of your Windows install and when you need to revert you can boot to a WinPE and deploy the WIM from a USB hard disk. Either way (WIM or sector-based restore) you will need somewhere to put the image (a USB hard disk, for example), a disk with the deploy software on (CloneZilla, WinPE etc.) and whatever commands to type to begin the restore process...

Comment: I say WIM because we've had a rate of a 30+GB image deployed in under 30mins... USB3 hard disk containing the WIM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances I'd suggest going with dd running from an Ubuntu live-cd, or Dism on a custom WinPE disc.
The thing is that using dd on Ubuntu is easy, but slow unless you complicate things. Building a custom WinPE disc to
use Dism is complicated, but you can do backups/restores fast. Instead I'll suggest cheating by using the Dism that
is included in the Windows 8.1 installation media, unfortunately this means clicking some extra buttons to get to the
command prompt. I know you want easy, and this is more medium, but it's free! You might also consider Norton Ghost, 
or Clonezilla which are easier. Googling something like "bootable hard drive backup tool" might help you find some others.

## Windows 8.1 Installation Disc Dism Method:

**Description:**

In order to do speedy backups it's generally a good idea to stay away from sector based backups, and go with file based
backups like this. File based backups are partition based, and don't include items written to the drives bootsectors, or
the partition's bootsectors. If you truely need to wipe the entire drive this method isn't for you, but if you just want
to wipe and restore the operating system partition, this will work.

**Pre-requisites:**

1. In addition to your operating system partition(s) you should have an empty partition to save your .wim image to.
2. Your OSP (Operating System Partition), and empty partition should both have labels so you can clearly identify them
   using DiskPart.

**Notes:**

- This assumes you only have 1 hard drive, and a dvd/cd drive. If you have any other storage media connected make sure
  to use the correct drive! You can use "list disk" in diskpart to see your drives.
- If you don't mind longer creation times, have a powerful enough system, and wish to generate smaller image files, you
  can change the compression settings from "/Compress:none" to "/Compress:max", the result is something equivalent in savings
  to that of .xz compression.

**Initial Steps:**

1. Go to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise , have you fake information handy,
   sign up, and download the iso file. (Don't worry you won't be installing Windows 8.1, you will just be using the
   installation discs copy of DISM instead of building your own WinPE disc with DISM. Microsft freely provides tools to build yourself a WinPE disc with Dism should you ever want to.).
2. Burn the iso to a dvd, and boot it up.

**Steps To Make An Image:**

3. Click "Next" at the setup screen, and then down in the bottom corner click "Repair your computer".
4. At the "Choose an option" screen choose "Troubleshoot".
5. At the "Troubleshoot" screen choose "Advanced options".
6. At the "Advanced options" screen choose "Command Prompt".
7. Before creating an image you need to make sure you know which partition you are imaging, and which you are saving to.
   To find out type "`diskpart`", and then in diskpart's prompt type "`list volume`".
8. In the command prompt type "exit".
9. To create your operating system image, in the command prompt type "
   `Dism /Capture-Image /Compress:none /CaptureDir:c:\ /ImageFile:d:\backup.wim /Name:"backup"`" Obviously you
   will need to change the drive letters to the proper ones for your locations as you previously found in diskpart.

**Steps To Restore An Image:**

10. Repeat steps 3, 4, 5, and 6. In the command prompt type "`diskpart`", then type 
    "`select disk 0`", then "list partition", "select partition 1" (substitute 1 for the number that is your
    Windows partition), "`format quick fs=ntfs`", and lastly "exit".
11. In commnd prompt type "`Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:d:\backup.wim /Index:1 /ApplyDir:c:\`" Obviously
    you will need to change the drive letters to the proper ones for your locations. This will
    restore your Windows backup. You can now reboot into it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but as you can see from the tag I need something that works with Windows 7. Is your answer equally valid for that version?

Comment: @bdesham The answer is intended for Windows 7 (though it can also be used for 8). The only reason I discuss using a Windows 8 disc is that Windows 7 discs don't have the required software included.